# Output V using * in C++

Tags: c++, for-loop

I have to make a V using astrisk * in C++ with loops..

Example:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/48upX.png

Anyone have any idea how it's done?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    for(int i = 10; i <= 20; i++){
        cout << setw(i);
        cout << "***" << endl;
    }
    for(int i = 30; i >= 20; i--){
        cout << setw(i);
        cout << "***" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I think my main trouble here is how to make the spaces? How to increase them dynamically during the for loop?

Comment: You should notice a relationship between `i` and the number of spaces you need for each part.

Comment: That looks more like an italic i to me...

Comment: Use `std::right`, `std::left` and some trickery with `std::setw`.

Comment: I thought of that too. But I don't know how to make "i" amount of spaces? I thought of starting the for loop from 10 and then going to 20, and for each time i is increased it adds one space before the ***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (int i=0;i<10;i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<i*2; j++)
        cout << " ";
    cout << "***";

    for (int j=0; j<2+(10-1-i)*4; j++)
        cout << " ";

    cout << "***" << endl;
}
```

spaces before stars from 1st line to last are: 0, 2, 4, 6, ....
that's lineNumber*2 = i*2 times.

we have ten lines. spaces between stars from last to first are: 2, 6, 10, 14, ....
that's 2 as constant + (totalNumberofLines-1-currentline)*4.
2 is the starting number of spaces. 4 is range.
-1 here because last line is 9 and 10-9=1. depends on loop counter starting point.

I hope that explains.

Comment: The first part is done, but the second isn't as I can see. Also, I think it's easier and simplier to be done with setw function.

Comment: when you are asked to do it as homework it's more likely expected that you use only loops. I think.

Comment: I kept numbers like this cause they mean something. the equation.

Comment: you are going to use those numbers in setw

Comment: It's not homework, it's exercises I'm doing on my own to learn c++. It's taken from a book which is used in school, but I already finished it. So... I want to learn more functions, such as setw, if that's ok.. I have done half the program, I only have problems integrating the both parts into one line together..

Comment: It is indeed 'correect', except there isn't 10 empty spaces in the beginning. However, do you mind if you explain the part in the for loops? What is the logic behind them?

Answer (score 1):

Not the best, but I try:

```
int main()
{
    for (int i = 0, s = 17, w = 4; i < 10; ++i, s -= 2, ++w)
    {
        std::string space;
        if (s >= 0)
            space.assign(s, ' ');
        else
            space = "";
        std::cout << std::right
                  << std::setw(w)
                  << "***" << space << ((i != 9) ?  "***\n" : "**");
    }
}
```

Comment: It does "work", with a few mistakes but it definitely does the job and can be easily fixed, except I don't really know what's going on. I have yet learned the function assign.

Comment: @user2943407 `assign` has several overloads which try to mimick the behavior of the `string` class's constructors. [Here is the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/assign)

Comment: @user2943407 `space.assign(s, ' ')` assigns the internal `char` array of `space` *s* spaces.